# Somando elementos de uma lista em Python

Tags: python-3.x, lista

Fiz o seguinte código para a questão do curso de Python da USP, porém o resultado está sendo barrado e no meu pc o código funciona perfeitamente.

```py
def soma_elementos(l):
    lista_somada = sum(l)
    print(lista_somada)


lista = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
soma_elementos(lista)
```

Tem algo errado ou deve ser por usar a função sum()?

Comment: valeu! retirei o print como você disse e troquei por return e o código passou.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Isso acontece porque as ferramentas de execução de testes verificam o resultado (retorno) da função que está sendo testada.

Neste seu caso específico você imprime o resultado (que é o resultado esperado) porém o retorno da função é None (em Python quando não é passado um valor de retorno então a função retorna None). Então a ferramenta não tem como avaliar o retorno da sua função. Pois o valor retornado foi `None`.

Sabendo disso, para resolver o problema, basta remover a função `print` e colocar um `return` em sua função.

Segue um exemplo:

```
def soma_elementos(l):
   return sum(l)
```